# Compojure Rest API: Show body response in JSON format

Tags: clojure, compojure, compojure-api

I am new to compojure api.

How can I show body response in JSON format?

Here is the code what I have written

**core.clj**

```
(ns clojure-dauble-business-api.core
  (:require [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all])
  (:require [ring.util.http-response :refer :all])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.dbdev :as dbdev])
  (:require [yesql.core :refer [defquery]])
  (:require [cheshire.core :as json])
  (:require [ring.util.response :as response])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.logic :as logic])
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.artwork :as artwork]))

(defapi app
  (GET "/hello" []
   (log/info "Function begins from here"
    :return [artwork/artwork]
    :summary "Returns list of artworks"
    (response/response (logic/artworks)))))
```

**Output of code is:**

```
:return [{:id java.lang.Integer, #schema.core.OptionalKey{:k :name} java.lang.String}]
:summary Returns list of artworks
{:status 200, :headers {}, :body [{"id":25,"name":"Garden"},{"id":27,"name":"Lord Of the Rings Statue"},{"id":32,"name":"DEFAULT"},{"id":33,"name":"Garden"},{"id":39,"name":"garden"},{"id":83,"name":"yyeye"},{"id":86,"name":"DEFAULT"},{"id":88,"name":"wera"},{"id":137,"name":""},{"id":149,"name":"DEFAULT"}]}
```

How can I show `:body` of response into JSON format.

I need to show data in this way

```
 [
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Garden"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "name": "Lord Of the Rings Statue"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "name": "DEFAULT"
  },
  {
    "id": 33,
    "name": "Garden"
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "name": "garden"
  },
  {
    "id": 83,
    "name": "yyeye"
  },
  {
    "id": 86,
    "name": "DEFAULT"
  },
  {
    "id": 88,
    "name": "wera"
  },
  {
    "id": 137,
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 149,
    "name": "DEFAULT"
  }
]
```

Comment: I got my mistake. I mistakenly wrote inside of log ``(log/info "Function begins from here"
    :return [artwork/artwork]
    :summary "Returns list of artworks"
    (response/response (logic/artworks)))))``

Answer (score 1):

I got answer and figured out where I am doing wrong.

```
(ns clojure-dauble-business-api.core
  (:require [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all])
  (:require [ring.util.http-response :refer :all])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.dbdev :as dbdev])
  (:require [yesql.core :refer [defquery]])
  (:require [cheshire.core :as json])
  (:require [ring.util.response :as response])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.logic :as logic])
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.artwork :as artwork]))

(defapi app
  (GET "/hello" []
   (log/info "Function begins from here"
    :return [artwork/artwork]
    :summary "Returns list of artworks"
    (response/response (logic/artworks)))))
```

**Should be**

```
(ns clojure-dauble-business-api.core
  (:require [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all])
  (:require [ring.util.http-response :refer :all])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.dbdev :as dbdev])
  (:require [yesql.core :refer [defquery]])
  (:require [cheshire.core :as json])
  (:require [ring.util.response :as response])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.logic :as logic])
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
  (:require [clojure-dauble-business-api.artwork :as artwork]))

(defapi app
  (GET "/hello" []
    (log/info "Function begins from here")
    :return [artwork/artwork]
    :summary "Return list of artworks"
    (ok (logic/artworks))))
```

Comment: Also, it's good to keep in mind that you don't need :require each time you use a library. It can simply be (:require [library1 :refer all][library2 :refer [abc]])